# Node.js object syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax

I've been learning node.js and fiddling around a bit until I encountered the "process" and "global" command in node console. When I run the "process" command I see the object with all its details.

**Here comes the question**:
What does these values mean syntax wise: [Getter], [Getter/Setter], [Function: something], and [Function]? Are these types? And some of them have function parameter names? Are they arrays? I can't wrap my head around these.

```
  binding: [Function: binding],
  _linkedBinding: [Function: _linkedBinding],
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    newListener: [ [Function: startListeningIfSignal], [Function] ],
    removeListener: [ [Function: stopListeningIfSignal], [Function] ],
    warning: [Function: onWarning],
    SIGWINCH: [Function]
  },
  _eventsCount: 4,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  domain: [Getter/Setter],
 
...
  _fatalException: [Function],
  setUncaughtExceptionCaptureCallback: [Function],
  hasUncaughtExceptionCaptureCallback: [Function: hasUncaughtExceptionCaptureCallback],
  emitWarning: [Function: emitWarning],
  nextTick: [Function: nextTick],
  _tickCallback: [Function: runNextTicks],
  _debugProcess: [Function: _debugProcess],
  _debugEnd: [Function: _debugEnd],
  _startProfilerIdleNotifier: [Function: _startProfilerIdleNotifier],
  _stopProfilerIdleNotifier: [Function: _stopProfilerIdleNotifier],
  stdout: [Getter],
  stdin: [Getter],
  stderr: [Getter],
  abort: [Function: abort],
  umask: [Function: wrappedUmask],
```

Comment: The console does not show you "the truth". It just tries to show you what's inside the object, and as it cannot unfold each and every reference, it'll abreviate nested properties by giving a quick summary what they are referencing (e.g. a function named abort). That's not JS syntax. "Are these types?" yes, kind of. Internal types of the JavaScript engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is the console's attempt to explain to you what is in each of these properties.  This is not Javascript syntax or Javascript language, just the console's way of explaining things.

Here are some explanations of some what you see:

`[Function]`             means there's a function reference in this property

`[Function: somename]`   means there's a function reference with a name in this property

`[Getter]`               means this property has a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

`[Object: null prototype]`  means this contains an object without a prototype

`[4]`                    means the property contains the value 4

`[undefined]`            means the property contains the value undefined

`[Getter/Setter]` means the property has both a setter and a getter

> Are these types?

Not entirely.  They are a description of what the property contains.  In some cases, it is a type such as `[Function]` or `[Object]`, but in other cases, it's just a value like `4` or `undefined` and in still other cases, it's telling you that is has a getter or a setter or both.  From the JS language point of view, these aren't all types, but rather a text description of what the property holds.

> And some of them have function parameter names?

Yes, if the console knows the function reference's name, then it is listed.  If it doesn't know the name (such as an anonymous function), then the name is  not listed.

> Are they arrays?

No.  The console just chose to use the bracket characters to delineate its description.  Nothing to do with arrays.

This format is just a shortcut convention that the console invented to tell you what is in each of these properties.